# Read only Edit Control

Tags: wix

I have an edit control that I would like to be read-only. I have set the attribute `Disabled="yes"` however my user cannot copy and paste from the control.

Is there any way around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Windows Installer does not support the read-only bit in the Edit control and, as you found, making the control disabled prevents all interaction with the control. This is one of many examples where the built in MSI UI is very limited.

Comment: Thanks rob, to solve this I added a copy button beside the edit control so that my user still has the functionality..:)